# How to automatically input in the WebBrowser control

Tags: vb.net

I'm quite very amateur in vb.net. When I type a text on textbox, it should be able to automatically input on the webbrowsercontrol and also how to click the button signin, wherein no getelementbyid.

Also I manage to get the 1st part correct, but when I click sign in button from inside browser, there seems to be a minor error. I've made a project like this one before long long time ago and can't find the source code of it anymore, so I'm starting from scratch again.

Website: https://app.coins.ph/welcome/login

Heres my code so far:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("username").InnerText = TextBox1.Text
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("class") 'Depending on how the source code is formatted on the tag, you may also try Element.OuterHTML, Element.InnerText and Element.OuterText in the line below
        If Element.OuterText.Contains("SIGN IN") Then
            Element.InvokeMember("click")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Element
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("password").InnerText = TextBox2.Text
End Sub
```

Comment: Take a few minutes to learn [how to ask.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please also see: [Under what circumstances may I add "urgent" or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569)

Comment: Urgh, when asking questions, please take a few extra seconds to add a useful title. Begging of that kind could apply to all 15M questions on the site, and (a) your question is not more important than others, (b) your question is creating editing work for volunteers, (c) you're essentially asking for downvotes that will harm your chances of getting good answers, (d) all of the above is really obvious.

Comment: "there seems to be a minor error" - what error? I don't know .net, but it looks like your question could do with some more detail. Note that people will not go to your website to find this information - you need to provide it for them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a couple of issues here. Let's start with the textbox inputs. If you look at the html source for that website's sign-in page, the inputs for username and password do not have an ID property, they only use Name. Moreover, GetElementsByTagName is searching for a html element of "username", not an "input" as it should. Given both of those issues, you should be using `Document.All("[elementName]")` to access those inputs. As for the sign-in part, as stated before, GetElementsByTagName is looking for html elements, so searching for the value "class" is not going to return anything you want. Instead, you should be looking for a "button" where the OuterText contains "SIGN IN". With all those changes applied, the code becomes:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        WebBrowser1.Navigate("https://app.coins.ph/welcome/login")
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
        WebBrowser1.Document.All("username").InnerText = TextBox1.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
        WebBrowser1.Document.All("password").InnerText = TextBox2.Text
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
            If Element.OuterText.Contains("SIGN IN") Then
                Element.InvokeMember("click")
                Exit For
            End If
        Next Element
    End Sub

End Class
```

> There is another problem once you run this code though

If you run the above example, you will see that the form-fields are properly filled in and the sign-in button is clicked successfully, however an error appears indicating that the form fields are still blank. Even if you use `WebBrowser1.Document.All("username").SetAttribute("value", TextBox1.Text)` to set the input's value as well, the same error occurs. This is likely because the website's developers are using some sort of javascript that is detecting keypresses for one reason or another...it's impossible to know why, but that's how it is. So you're left with actually simulating key presses yourself. If you do that, the website will successfully log in with the username and password. You have two ways of doing this. The cleaner way is to just send all the keys at once and log in like so:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    WebBrowser1.Focus()
    WebBrowser1.Document.All("username").Focus()
    For Each c As Char In TextBox1.Text.ToCharArray
        SendKeys.SendWait(c)
    Next
    WebBrowser1.Document.All("password").Focus()
    For Each c As Char In TextBox2.Text.ToCharArray
        SendKeys.SendWait(c)
    Next
    For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
        If Element.OuterText.Contains("SIGN IN") Then
            Element.InvokeMember("click")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Element
End Sub
```

However, if you still want each character to appear as you type, to mirror the functionality of the TextChanged event logic you are currently using you would have to use the KeyPress event and basically forward the keystrokes like this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    For Each Element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
        If Element.OuterText.Contains("SIGN IN") Then
            Element.InvokeMember("click")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next Element
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    WebBrowser1.Focus()
    WebBrowser1.Document.All("username").Focus()
    SendKeys.SendWait(e.KeyChar)
    TextBox1.Focus()
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox2.KeyPress
    WebBrowser1.Focus()
    WebBrowser1.Document.All("password").Focus()
    SendKeys.SendWait(e.KeyChar)
    TextBox2.Focus()
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, this seems to solve my problem that I've been stuck for quite a while doing trial and error. Thank you so much, this really helps big time.

Comment: I've run across another problem. Is there anyway I can contact you directly by facebook maybe or something? Really need your help this time again and in the future for some references, thank you

Comment: Just post your questions on this website, there are a lot of developers who are way better than me on StackOverflow

Comment: Heres the problem now I've encountered:  https://snag.gy/Eusdab.jpg(pic)

Heres my current code as well: https://pastebin.com/r6n2ga0X

Sorry if I put my new question on this comment, I'm quite new to stackoverflow just trying to answer here, and also I can't seem to make new questions yet again

Comment: @KennOmisol, the best way to say "thank you" on SO is to accept and upvote answers you find helpful.

Comment: @KenOmisol, I recommend you post a new question.  You are not likely to get another answer by asking questions in the comments. You should read the help section carefully to figure out how you can get your question ban lifted.  The key is to ask higher quality questions.  BTW, I upvoted this answer to thank soohoonigan for his effort.

Comment: [Here is good advice on how to get you question ban lifted.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th)

Comment: The comments don't really work for questions, I also can't really test because I can't log into that site. Only thing that sticks out to me is a typo in the class name, wallet__balance has two underscores. Also not checking for class name correctly. Try `For Each CurElement As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div") ... If CurElement.GetAttribute("className") = "wallet__balance" Then`. That's all I can really help in comments, and these comments will probably be removed by mods for extended discussion, so you'll have to post a new question if that doesn't work.

Comment: @soohoonigan, Ooooh, you're really a lifesaver! Didn't notice two underscores on it, no wonder I keep on repeating my mistakes. Thank you, thank you so much.